# Why does it still put in starboard even when its not the right amount of reactions? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a starboard command and here is the problem. The starcount is set to 3 but when I react only 1 time, it still puts it in the starboard

Here is the code

```
        if (user.partial) await user.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.emoji.name === "⭐"){
                if (reaction.count == starboardnum || 3){
// rest of code
}
```

Image link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUeoK.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error most likely has to do with == evaluating before ||, meaning that if `reaction.count` isn't equal to `starboardnum`, it uses the `3` in the if statement, which is a truthy value in Javascript.

The fix is simple, just put parentheses around `starboardnum || 3`, like this:

```
if (reaction.count == (starboardnum || 3)){
```